# Javascript run function only once and avoid running again in refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing TimeAgo jQuery plugin that calculates time since a given datetime.
Example: 4 minutes ago

I developed it to be according to user`s timezone and it works ok but when it refreshs automaticly it repeats the minus/plus hours according to time zone..

I want to add value only once!

JS code:

```
 (function($) {
    $.timeago = function(timestamp) {
        if (timestamp instanceof Date) {
            return inWords(timestamp);
        } else if (typeof timestamp === "string") {
            return inWords($.timeago.parse(timestamp));
        } else if (typeof timestamp === "number") {
            return inWords(new Date(timestamp));
        } else {
            return inWords($.timeago.datetime(timestamp));
        }
    };
    var $t = $.timeago;

    $.extend($.timeago, {
        settings: {
            refreshMillis: 60000,
            allowFuture: false,
            strings: {
                prefixAgo: null,
                prefixFromNow: null,
                suffixAgo: "قبل",
                suffixFromNow: "من الآن",
                seconds: "اقل من دقيقة",
                minute: "دقيقة",
                minutes: "%d دقيقة",
                hour: "ساعة",
                hours: "%d ساعة",
                day: "يوم",
                days: "%d يوم",
                month: "شهر",
                months: "%d اشهر",
                year: "سنة",
                years: "%d سنين",
                wordSeparator: " ",
                numbers: []
            }
        },
        inWords: function(distanceMillis) {
            var $l = this.settings.strings;
            var prefix = $l.prefixAgo;
            var suffix = $l.suffixAgo;
            if (this.settings.allowFuture) {
                if (distanceMillis < 0) {
                    prefix = $l.prefixFromNow;
                    suffix = $l.suffixFromNow;
                }
            }

            var seconds = Math.abs(distanceMillis) / 1000;
            var minutes = seconds / 60;
            var hours = minutes / 60;
            var days = hours / 24;
            var years = days / 365;

            function substitute(stringOrFunction, number) {
                var string = $.isFunction(stringOrFunction) ? stringOrFunction(number, distanceMillis) : stringOrFunction;
                var value = ($l.numbers && $l.numbers[number]) || number;
                return string.replace(/%d/i, value);
            }

            var words = seconds < 45 && substitute($l.seconds, Math.round(seconds)) ||
        seconds < 90 && substitute($l.minute, 1) ||
        minutes < 45 && substitute($l.minutes, Math.round(minutes)) ||
        minutes < 90 && substitute($l.hour, 1) ||
        hours < 24 && substitute($l.hours, Math.round(hours)) ||
        hours < 42 && substitute($l.day, 1) ||
        days < 30 && substitute($l.days, Math.round(days)) ||
        days < 45 && substitute($l.month, 1) ||
        days < 365 && substitute($l.months, Math.round(days / 30)) ||
        years < 1.5 && substitute($l.year, 1) ||
        substitute($l.years, Math.round(years));

            var separator = $l.wordSeparator === undefined ? " " : $l.wordSeparator;
            return $.trim([prefix, suffix, words].join(separator));
        },
        parse: function(iso8601) {
            var s = $.trim(iso8601);
            s = s.replace(/\.\d+/, ""); // remove milliseconds
            s = s.replace(/-/, "/").replace(/-/, "/");
            s = s.replace(/T/, " ").replace(/Z/, " UTC");
            s = s.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)\:?(\d\d)/, " $1$2"); // -04:00 -> -0400
            return new Date(s);
        },
        datetime: function(elem) {
            var iso8601 = $t.isTime(elem) ? $(elem).attr("datetime") : $(elem).attr("title");
            return $t.parse(iso8601);
        },
        isTime: function(elem) {
            // jQuery's `is()` doesn't play well with HTML5 in IE
            return $(elem).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() === "time"; // $(elem).is("time");
        }
    });

    $.fn.timeago = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.each(refresh);

        var $s = $t.settings;
        if ($s.refreshMillis > 0) {
            setInterval(function() { self.each(refresh); }, $s.refreshMillis);
        }
        return self;
    };

    function refresh() {
        var data = prepareData(this);
        var dt = data.datetime;
        if (!isNaN(dt)) {
            $(this).text(inWords(dt));
        }
        return this;
    }

    function prepareData(element) {
        element = $(element);
        if (!element.data("timeago")) {
            element.data("timeago", { datetime: $t.datetime(element) });
            var text = $.trim(element.text());
            if (text.length > 0 && !($t.isTime(element) && element.attr("title"))) {
                element.attr("title", text);
            }
        }
        return element.data("timeago");
    }

    function get_time_zone_offset() {
        var current_date = new Date();
        return -current_date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

    }

    function inWords(date) {
        date.setHours(date.getHours() + get_time_zone_offset());
        return $t.inWords(distance(date));
    }

    function distance(date) {
        return (new Date().getTime() - date.getTime());
    }

    // fix for IE6 suckage
    document.createElement("span");
    document.createElement("time");
} (jQuery));
```

Comment: You mean you don't want to run it again on page refresh ?

Comment: What about setting and checking a cookie?

Comment: not page refresh but jquery refresh

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set a Cookie and store weather or not it has been ran. So the first time you run you check if the cookie exist. If it doesn't you run your code then set the cookie. Set the cookie to be a session cookie so that it will expire the next time closes their browser.

Comment: thanks but it wont work!! its a jquery refresh not whole page refresh only the SPAN value refreshs